# Emacs 24.4 and multi-term

Tags: emacs, ansi-term

I read [the following](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2014-02/msg00120.html) on the Emacs list about Emacs multi-term:

> > Because of changes in `advice.el`, `multi-term.el` does not work anymore. These changes surely mark the emerge into a bright future. But I hate them because I can **no longer** use my beloved multi-term.
> >     Unfortunately the development of multi-term is abandoned.

However, today I saw a new update when updating my Emacs packages:

> > multi-term **20140316**.... installed  Managing multiple terminal buffers in Emacs.

The date sems to be March 16 of 2014. With this, my question is:

- Where did this update come from? Is there a `multi-term` repository that is actively maintained?
- If multi-term is not compatible with Emacs 24.4, will the functionality of multi-term be available in Emacs? (e.g. automatically closing the buffer when exiting the terminal)

Answer (score 2):

It does not seem that `multi-term`'s development has been abandoned. Check the source on its [emacswiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/multi-term.el). The change log in the file says

```
;;; Change log:
;;
;; 2014/03/17   Andy Stewart
;;      * Swap key binding of `term-send-raw' and `term-send-input', i think it's better send yank data when user hit ctrl+m.
;;
;; 2014/01/16
;;      * Fix breakage introduced in Emacs 24.4.
;;
```

The latest change was made yesterday. This is where the update came from. Also the breakage due to 24.4 seems to fixed.

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know if there is a GitHub repository associated with it? How was this code updated on EmacsWiki?

Comment: @user815423426 there is a mirror here(https://github.com/emacsmirror/multi-term) but it does not seem to be updated regularly. `How was this code updated on EmacsWiki?` I guess the author uploaded the new version on the wiki.

Comment: AFAIK, the wiki version is canonical.  Melpa pulls it from there.